# Will pure CSS allow me to make a grid with one large item and subsequent items of equal width but unequal height?

Tags: html, css

I'm exploring different ways of doing grids. I'm trying to make a block of HTML that's a minimal as possible so I can let the CSS do the heavy lifting. As you can see in the code snippet, the basic idea is:

- big block in the first slot on the left
- every other block is the same width, but the heights aren't guaranteed to stay the same

```css
#items {
  width: 240px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#items .item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#items .item:nth-child(1) {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}

#items .item:nth-child(2) {
  height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div id="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
```

The HTML is wonderfully minimal, but you can see the problem: 4 should be underneath 2 instead of just to the right of it. Clearing doesn't work because it clears 1 as well. The only options I found on my own were to 1) put 2/3 and 3/4 in wrapper divs, or 2) use JS to equalize the heights of 2/3 and 3/4. Neither solution is ideal. I also tried putting item 1 outside of the outside `<div>`, but couldn't seem to solve the problem that way either.

Is there a solution where I can turn this HTML into the grid I want?

Comment: `float: left;` is going to behave exactly as it is. If you know what the widths are going to be, you could just create columns to house each div... Might not be ideal, but a solution none-the-less.

Comment: What you're describing is 'masonry': See link http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Masonry is a JS Library. Not pure CSS and HTML code. And does what I already specified (using an algorithm to decide which height is best and where to arrange everything.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that floats will always float if there is any room to float.  In other words.  Because 55 has 5 px of extra space the next object floating will float to the right of it because of the 5px remaining and the next object will float to the right of the next longest object.  It's not smart enough and there is no way that I know of to get it to objectively re-order the floating objects for you such that it minimizes all the space.  Your best bet if possible is to re-order the div's such that objects with same height are next to each other.

Comment: Here's a sample illustrating the problem a bit clearer than your original I think: http://jsfiddle.net/wntLrkgc/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine, bro.
Just delete this:

```
#items .item:nth-child(2) {
height: 55px;
}
```

Thats it, useful stuff too. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that was added to simulate height differences from element to element.

Comment: Oh, wait. It seems youre trying to achieve that 2 with a different height there. My bad!. Let's work out another solution.

Comment: This answer made me laugh so hard -- ty!

Comment: Just let me get something clear here, do you want all of the grid boxes below the one with a different height to move a bit down depending on its height (This time, being 2 the different one, 4 and 8 would move down). Or do you want the 2 to fix itself in a centered way to leave the space for the others?.

Comment: @WorldOfKhriztian I would want 4 to be under 2, 5 to be under 3, and 6-9 to be in one row underneath 1, 4, and 5.

Comment: @Brendan
So you wouldn't mind that, let's say, 2's height make it go down to row 3 so it's all over them, or would you want it to fix it self to not cover any of the others.
Another work-around would be, making that 2's height is either the same of the others or if higher force it to be twice the height of the others occupying 2 rows. It would look smooth and you wouldnt need anything else.

Comment: @WorldOfKhriztian My nth-child set a height to 55px while the others are at 50px; I'd like to have a way to have 4 clear that 5px of extra space without clearing 1 altogether. In my real-life use case, I'm not setting heights on the small elements at all; I'm setting the widths but I can't necessarily predict what the heights are going to be. With the other answer given and with some additional thought, I don't think that what I want to do is possible.

Comment: What I mean is that you NEED a little script for this or a library that can help you achieve with CSS that:
Everytime any of your grid boxes surpasses the height it automatically give itself a height of itself by 2.
In other words: if(grid.box.height > 110){ grid.box.height = 220} theres no other possible ways, unless you want an assymetrical looking grid.

Comment: @WorldOfKhriztian Seems that way. Thanks for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: You're welcome mate, thanks for bringing stuff to look into!.